# onClick for link element doesnt work when trying to invoke a js function (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null)

Tags: javascript, onclick, modelattribute

Here I'm trying to send a http request to my spring controller once an icon is clicked that is displayed with a validation for a model attribute.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 page-title-section"></div>
      <c:if test="${viewUsers}">
        <div class="col-sm-4 page-actions-section">
            <div class="page-actions">
                <div class="page-action">
                        <a id="loadUserIcon">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                            <h5>Add User</h5>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${viewRoles}">
            <div class="col-sm-4 page-actions-section">
                <div class="page-actions">
                    <div class="page-action">
                        <a id="loadRoleIcon">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                            <h5>Add Role</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </div>
```

The js to send the request once the icon is clicked :

```
    (function() {
    document.getElementById("loadUserIcon").onclick = function() {
        window.location = 'loadUser?id=' + 0;
    };
})();

   (function() {
    document.getElementById("loadRoleIcon").onclick = function() {
        window.location = 'loadRole?id=' + 0;
    };
})();
```

So now the separate icons are displayed with each model attribute validation and the first function is invoked once the 'Add User' icon is clicked but i cant seem to invoke this second function even though the icon is displayed with the model attribute validation. What could have been gone wrong here?

The error on the console once the 'Add Role' icon is clicked :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
at load:496
at load:500
```

these line numbers are directed to the second js function

Answer (score 0):

Any error on console ?

Where you put the scripts?
You should put them into `body.onload` handler or just before the end tag `</body>`.

Comment: Error `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`.   It seems the element `loadUserIcon` or `loadRoleIcon` is not ready while you call `.onclick`

Comment: It must be code placement issue. As @iamabhishek says, just have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Include your JavaScript code, either at below the `</body>` tag, or load the functions upon **DOM ready** or **onload**.

I changed the code a bit for JSFiddle and its working fine, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/045L2xvj/

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 page-title-section"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 page-actions-section">
            <div class="page-actions">
                <div class="page-action">
                        <a href="#" id="loadUserIcon">
                            <h5>Add User</h5>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="col-sm-4 page-actions-section">
                <div class="page-actions">
                    <div class="page-action">
                        <a href="#" id="loadRoleIcon">
                            <h5>Add Role</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

And JS code:

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById("loadUserIcon").onclick = function() {
        alert('Add user');
    };
})();

   (function() {
    document.getElementById("loadRoleIcon").onclick = function() {
       alert('Add role');
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to wrap the js functions too with the model attribute validation to eliminate elements getting null.

```
<c:if test="${viewUsers}">
   <script>
        document.getElementById('loadUserIcon').onclick = function () {
            window.location = 'loadUser?id=' + 0;
        };
   </script>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${viewRoles}">
   <script>
        document.getElementById('loadRoleIcon').onclick = function () {
            window.location = 'loadRole?id=' + 0;
        };
   </script>
</c:if>
```